# Starting Electron React JS application via cli WITH additional arguments

Tags: reactjs, electron, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, package.json

I got my application all done and everything works fine.
However the application needs to be runable via a command, which will be executed by another application.
My **package.json** scripts look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run-script start\" \"npm run-script electron:start\"",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
```

Now the problem is, that I need to be able to add arguments such as port and pageToShow for starting. I know I can edit it just like this f.e.:
`..."concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run-script start\" \"npm run-script electron:start port mainPage\"",`

This way, of course it will work. But now imagine, running *npm run electron:serve* - I'd have to manually change the script in my **package.json** to the according port and page, for the arguments to work, which the other application obviously won't do.

What I want is something similar to this command: `npm run eletron:serve port mainPage`.
If I were to run the command like that, Electron simply would never receive the arguments.

At the moment I'm catching the arguments in my main process like this:

```
const arg = process.argv;
const arguments = {
  mode: arg[2],
  port: arg[3],
  pageToShow: arg[4]
}
```

I feel like I'm drawing a blank here, and just not seeing the solution.

I tried different variations of the **package.json** scripts, but none of them worked. Either the arguments didn't go trough at all and the starting process would just stop, or they would go trough and Electron couldn't find them.

Help is massively appreciated!